# Doing int64 conversion in Telerik Reporting

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-reporting

I want to convert a `string` to an `int` using the `CInt` function, but it can only can fields to `int32` and if my fields is bigger than that, I get this error:

```
value is either too large or too small for an int32
```

How can I use `int64` conversion in Telerik Reporting?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CLng`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck4c5842(v=vs.84).aspx) to return a 64-bit integer (`Long`)

Comment: I am getting this error in telerik reporting . An error has occurred while processing Report , The expression contains undefined call CLng().

Comment: @MohammadaliGhods Looks like Telerik does not support that VB function.  Can you do the conversion before you hit the reporting layer?

Comment: What do you need to convert it in the reporting layer for?

Comment: Because I am getting this data from db directly

Comment: So you're connecting directly to a table?  Can you not use SQL instead and do the conversion there?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure Telerik Reports support C# conversions so just do Convert.ToInt64(Parameter/Value) and it should work.